# In Python how to modify a list with a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am unsure on how to get something like this to work.

```
data= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def convert(temp):
   for element in temp:
      element = 2
   return temp

data = convert(data)
print(data) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Something like this works as expected

```
data= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def convert(temp):
   for i in range(len(temp)):
      temp[i] = 2
   return temp

data = convert(data)
print(data) #[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I am wondering if there is any way to make the first example work(the list would become just 2s)

Comment: `return [2 for element in list]`

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @MauriceMeyer import to understand, that isn't modifying the list at all.

Comment: @ggorlen it is absolutely **not a copy**

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it's the same id. So it's a reference and immutable. I'll remove my post in case it was misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory: don't use `list` as a variable or parameter name, since it overwrites the builtin `list` type.

The reason the first example doesn't work is that each *value* from the list is assigned to the variable named `element`, but reassigning `element` to a *different* value only modifies that variable; it doesn't mutate the original value in the list.

The second example does what you want because the `[]` operator allows you to mutate the list.

Note also that there is an example between mutating the original list and returning a new list that's a modified version of the original!

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> def convert(a):
...     """Returns a new list filled with 2s."""
...     return [2 for i in a]
...
>>> def mutate(a):
...     """Modifies the list to fill it with 2s."""
...     for i in range(len(a)):
...         a[i] = 2
...     return a
...
>>> convert(data)
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> data
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> mutate(data)
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> data
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Both functions return a list that's filled with 2s, but `convert` returns a new list (leaving the original `data` unchanged unless you assign the new value to it), whereas `mutate` modifies the original list as well.

Finally, there is a way to use the `[]` operator as a shortcut to mutate the entire list at once:

```
>>> def mutate(a):
...     a[:] = [2 for _ in a]
...
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> mutate(data)
>>> data
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```